# Conditional formatting on multiple rows with different names in Excel

Tags: conditional-formatting

I have 4 names in column A

SEGMENT - ADULT ORG 
SEGMENT - CORE 
SEGMENT - LIGHT 
SEGMENT - PROACTIVE HEALTH

I want to use a conditional formatting where each time it finds one of them it colors the entire row, each row should be different colored for eg SEGMENT - ADULT ORG - Red, 
SEGMENT - CORE - Blue etc.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Clear any existing CF, select entire sheet and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$A1="SEGMENT - ADULT ORG"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Repeat for the other three colours, adjusting the text and formatting to suit.